# How to view a QJsonValue while debuging exe with IDA

Tags: ida, debugging, qt

I'm step by step debugging a program in IDA.
The program uses the Qt-toolkit.
The function that I'm stepping through is handling a `json` document.
For example here it is accessing the key `workgroup` and putting its value in `v15` (pseudocode):
[image: Ida pseudocode]

`v15` represents `RAX`, but when I take a look add the address `RAX`, I do expect to see the `workgroup` value but instead I see just zeros:
[image: RAX in memory]

How can I see the textual value of the `workgroup` key of this `json` document?